# Select the last non-NULL value when current row is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know that there are a lot of solutions for this but unfortunately I cannot use partition or keyword TOP. Nothing I tried on earlier posts works.

My table looks like this:

[image]

The result I want is when any completion percentage is `NULL` it should get the value from last non-value completion percentage, like this:

[image]

I tried this query but nothing works. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
SELECT sequence,project_for_lookup,
CASE WHEN completion_percentage IS NOT NULL THEN completion_percentage 
ELSE 
     (SELECT max(completion_percentage) FROM [project_completion_percentage] AS t2
     WHERE t1.project_for_lookup=t2.project_for_lookup and
           t1.sequence<t2.sequence and
           t2.completion_percentage IS NOT null

END 

FROM [project_completion_percentage] AS t1
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative window functions.  So, I would suggest `outer apply`:

```
select cp.projectname, cp.sequence,
       coalesce(cp.completion_percentage, cp2.completion_percentage) as completion_percentage
from completion_percentage cp outer apply
     (select top 1 cp2.*
      from completion_percentage cp2
      where cp2.projectname = cp.projectname and
            cp2.sequence < cp.sequence and
            cp2.completion_percentage is not null
     order by cp2.sequence desc
    ) cp2;
```

Comment: I cannot use keyword TOP or outer apply. It gives error

Comment: Found OUTER but expected end of expression

Comment: @NishaNethani  . . . I would then conclude that you are not using SQL Server 2008, as indicated by the tag on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? It seems to for me. You were missing a parenthesis and had the sequence backwards.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465f2/4

```
SELECT sequence,project_for_lookup,
CASE WHEN completion_percentage IS NOT NULL THEN completion_percentage 
ELSE 
     (
         SELECT max(completion_percentage) 
         FROM [project_completion_percentage] AS t2
         WHERE t1.project_for_lookup=t2.project_for_lookup 

           -- sequence was reversed. You're on the row t1, and want t2 that is from a prior sequence.
           and t2.sequence<t1.sequence  
           and t2.completion_percentage IS NOT null

     --missing a closing paren
     ) 
END 

FROM [project_completion_percentage] AS t1
```